# Since the CGI module is slated to be deprecated in Python 3.13, what is a good substitution for cgi.FieldStorage?

Tags: python, web, cgi

I tried to use multipart, email.message, html.parse and requests but none seem to be doing what I need, which is getting the fields of an HTML form. Any suggestions?

Comment: At the website pythoncgi.net I have created mycgi.py that replaces the stdlib cgi.py that will be deprecated using [multipart](https://pypi.org/project/multipart/)

Comment: Thanks Stan. Can you share a simple example using multipart to read form values?

Comment: I have a simple example on the website I mentioned, also try https://pypi.org/project/legacy-cgi/ as a substitute also.